# Elastic search 5, search from list by sublist

Tags: list, nest, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to search from an object that has a list property.
I need to be able to select all object that contains all sublist items.

ex :
If my object has [A,B,C] it should be returned for the given querys :
[A], [A,B], [A,B,C], [A,C], [C,A] ... (Input order doesn't have to match)

But if the sublist contains any element that is not part of the object list, it should not be returned.

ex :
[D], [A,D] ...
Those querys should not be valid.

I've managed to do it for the query with an existing sublist, but not when any item of the sublist doesn't exists.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: How is the field that contains `[A,B,C]` mapped?

Answer (score 0):

Use comma seperate for sublist query item as a value for match query and set operator value to "and" as following:

Sample of document:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "One",
  "tags": ["A","B","C"]
}
```

For sublist:[A,B]:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "tags": {
        "query": "A,B",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I test in ElasticSearch 5.6.0 and 6.1.2

Comment: I've just tried it, it's not working (elastic search 6)

Comment: plz add sample of document and tried query to question, for checking it

Comment: Here is a sample document
`"_index": "test_index",
"_type": "mapping",
"_id": "1",
"_score": 0.2876821,
"_source": {
"id": 1,
"tags": [ "A","C","B"]
}`
I've tried your query sample, it works fine with "A" but as soon as I add other caracters with comma to separate, its not working

Comment: I've managed to write the query
`{
"query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": {"tags": "B"}},
            { "match": {"tags": "E"}},
 { "match": {"tags": "A"}}
          ]
        }
      }

}`

Thank you

Comment: @tibere, I test my answer in elasticsearch 6.1.2, that is work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A`, `B`, `C`, etc are mapped as [`keyword` types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html), multiple `bool` query `filter` clauses would be one way

```
var response = client.Search<User>(s => s
    .Query(q => +q
        .Term(f => f.Badges, "A") && +q
        .Term(f => f.Badges, "B") && +q
        .Term(f => f.Badges, "C")
    )
);
```

generates the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "badges": {
              "value": "A"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "badges": {
              "value": "B"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "badges": {
              "value": "C"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

A user document would need to have *at least* all of `A`, `B` and `C` badges to be considered a match.

A user document may well have other badges in addition to `A`, `B` and `C`; if you need to find documents that have *exactly* `A`, `B` and `C`, take a look at the [`terms_set` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html) with a `minimum_should_match*` value set to the number of passed terms.